# Change Specific Div background color by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how are you guys?! well I have a question. I have a link on top of a div called "section2" what I need is to change the Div background color on hover and keep that new color until you hover on link number two, background color of that div should change. I don't need to change the background color of the Link, I just need to change dinamically the background color of the div from behind.

```
<script language="javascript">

$(function(){
$("#changer").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var body = document.getElementById("section2"),
    green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
    white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

if(body.css("backgroundColor") !== green){
  body.css("backgroundColor",green);
}else{
  body.css("backgroundColor",white);
}
});
})

</script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="section2" align="center">
    <a href="#" id="changer">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. Could you please narrow it down to a specific problem? What exactly have you tried? What is the problem with what you've got so far?

Comment: Show us the HTML markup (DOM) including link number two please - and specify which background color should change when which link is clicked

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! now is working:)! thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$(function () {
    $('#changer').hover(function () {
        $('#section2').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });

    $('#reset').hover(function () {
        $('#section2').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
})
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bngLvjv1/1/)

Comment: Thanks! at the end I used this one and runs perfectly, thanks Ahs! and thanks everyone!

Comment: And could you tell me how to run a smooth transition between colors? is that possible? thanks!

Comment: Add `transition: background-color 0.5s;` to the `#section2` CSS [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/bngLvjv1/2/). And your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Native HTML elements don't have `css` method, this is jQuery one. So your code for `body` should be:

```
var body = $("#section2"),
```

Entire demo:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#changer").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var body = $("#section2"),
            green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
            white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

        if (body.css("backgroundColor") !== green) {
            body.css("backgroundColor", green);
        } else {
            body.css("backgroundColor", white);
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section2" align="center">
    <a href="#" id="changer">Click me</a>
</div>
```

However comparing CSS property value for background color is **very** unreliable. You would better compare/check classes:

```js
$("#changer").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#section2").toggleClass('green white');
});
```

```css
.green {background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);}
.white {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section2" class="white" align="center">
    <a href="#" id="changer">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, the css property "background-color" would return "green" if it was set to "rgb(0, 128, 0)".

Answer (score 0):

Reference the items using JQuery as so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#changer").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var body = $("#section2"),
            green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
            white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

        if (body.css("backgroundColor") !== green) {
            body.css("backgroundColor", green);
        } else {
            body.css("backgroundColor", white);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to control `$("#section2")` background-color property using CSS classes:

```
#section2.green {
  background-color: green;
}

#section2.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

So, using jQuery to add background-color:

```
$(function () {
    $("#changer").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var body = $("#section2");

        if (body.hasClass('green')) {
            body.removeClass('green')
              .addClass('white');
        } else {
            body.removeClass('white')
              .addClass('green');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following approached worked,

```
$(function() {
    $("#changer").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var body = $("#section2");
        if(body.css("background-color").indexOf("rgb(0, 128, 0)") == -1 ) {                             
            body.css("background-color","rgb(0, 128, 0)");
        }else{
          body.css("background-color","rgb(255, 255, 255)");
        }
    });
})
```